# Пытаюсь создать видеотеку в СИ

Tags: c

Когда запрашиваю поиск по названию фильма, программа должна выводит всю информацию по видеокассете, но численные переменные выводит некорректно. В чем ошибка? Помогите пожалуйста!

clear.c

```
    #include "main.h"
    #include "search.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

   void search(int *num, system *base)
{
char name[50];   
printf("Введите название фильма: ");
scanf("%s", &name);
for(int i = 0; i<*num; i++)
{
    if(strcmp(name, base[i].name)==0)
    {
        printf("Номер касеты: %d \n", &base[i].number);
        printf("Название касеты: %s \n", base[i].name);
        printf("Страна: %s \n", base[i].country);
        printf("Продолжительность фильма: %d \n", &base[i].span);
        printf("Жанр фильма: %s \n", base[i].genre);
        printf("Дата: %d:%d:%d \n", &base[i].day, &base[i].mounth, &base[i].year);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nТакой фильм не найден!\n");
    }
   }
  }
```

main.c

```
#include "main.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include "add.h"
#include "clear.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

  int main()
 {
     system base[100];
     int num = 0;
     char name_file[40] = "export.txt";
name_file;
int key = 0;
while (1) {
    key = menu();
    switch (key)
    {
        case 1:
            add(&num, base);
            break;
        case 2:
            clear(&num, base);
            break;
        case 3:
            search(&num, base);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error! \n");
            break;
    }                 
  }
}
```

Вот, что выводит в терминале:

```
     Меню:
     1. Добавить фильм
     2. Удалить фильм
     3. Поиск фильма по его названию
     4. Поиск фильма по его жанру и стране
     5. Поиск касет по дате
     0. Выход
     1
     Номер видеокасеты: 1
     Название фильма: кек
     Страна, где был снят фильм: Россия 
     Продолжительность фильма: 120
     Жанр фильма; комедия
     Дата приобретения касеты (через пробел день месяц год): 12 12 2016

     OK!
    Меню:
    1. Добавить фильм
    2. Удалить фильм
    3. Поиск фильма по его названию
    4. Поиск фильма по его жанру и стране
    5. Поиск касет по дате
    0. Выход
    3
    Введите название фильма: кек
    Номер касеты: 1469577280 
    Название касеты: кек 
    Страна: Россия 
    Продолжительность фильма: 1469577272 
    Жанр фильма: комедия 
    Дата: 1469577276:1469577284:1469577288
```

Вот ссылка на весь код, если что: https://yadi.sk/d/2_edazr03JXSBb

Comment: Вы бы все таки не давали 2 копии одного кода под видом разных файлов...

Comment: @Harry, дико извиняюсь...Не углядел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы же выводите не значения переменных, а их адреса:

```
printf("Дата: %d:%d:%d \n", &base[i].day, &base[i].mounth, &base[i].year);
```

Это при считывании адреса нужно передавать, а при выводе - сами значения:

```
printf("Дата: %d:%d:%d \n", base[i].day, base[i].mounth, base[i].year);
```